# How can I get the EXIF data of the image through UIImagePickerController or QBImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

I need to get the desired latitude and longitude of the image uploaded at my end at given location, so that I can use the same in future.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one It may help ful to you

```
-(void) locationConfigureAppearance{
   [m_LocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
   [m_LocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    m_LocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    m_LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    m_LocationManager.delegate = self;
    m_LocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeFitness;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [m_LocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [m_LocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [m_LocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
     [m_LocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
 }

 #pragma mark - locationManager delegate Methods


 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
 {
   CLLocation* newLocation = [locations lastObject];



     m_GPSCoordinate = newLocation.coordinate;

      self.SelectedLattitude = m_GPSCoordinate.latitude;

      self.SelectedLongitude = m_GPSCoordinate.longitude;

      NSLog(@"self.SelectedLattitude = %f %f",self.SelectedLattitude,self.SelectedLongitude);


 }
```